# ADB reject shell command (cat/proc/3655/stat):closed

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator

I'm using ubuntu 16.10. When I start my emulator from android studio I got this error:

> "ADB reject shell command (cat/proc/3655/stat):closed"

And its not opening. But I can run emulator from command line by following command:

> "LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6' ~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_25"

And it shows the warning message:

> "emulator: WARNING: encryption is off"

Answer (score 0):

It may be occur due to your 64bit linux didn't match to the avd you installed. Try copy 'lib' folder from your Android sdk location -> ../Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/qt/lib to ../Android/Sdk/tools/lib/qt/lib

Comment: in my sdk lib64 folder is not available